# TFS 2015 Linux Build Agent Configuration Throwing 401 error

Tags: linux, tfs-2015, agent

I am trying to configure a Linux agent for TFS 2015 update 3. When it prompts for entering information for configuration, it gives 401 error:

```
Raj@Ubuntu123:~/Linux_agent$ node agent/vsoagent
Enter alternate username > domain\<username>
Enter alternate password >
Enter server url > http://<hostname:port>/tfs
Enter agent name > Agent1
Enter Pool name > Linux
Enter force basic (enter is false) >
Error starting the agent
Failed Request: Unauthorized(401) - http://<hostname:port>/tfs/_apis/connectionData
```

I have checked all access. Access looks fine. The user has access in admin group (checked Team Foundation Administration Console- User's name is present in "Administration Console Users") and also to the agent pool. As it was 401 error, I gave access to all the groups present in TFS to the user but still it gives this error.

I was able to configure the agent in another TFS machine (TFS 2015 update 2). I have cross verified access in both the machines. It looks same. What am I missing? Please help me resolve this.

Comment: url is http://<hostname:port>/tfs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your TFS server configured to accept Basic Authentication and does it have SSL enabled with a trusted certificate? This is an important prerequisite to use the Linux agents.

Given the URI you've posted and the fact that you're using `domain\user`, I highly suspect that neither is true.

The [vso-agent repository explains how to configure the Linux agent as well as the TFS server](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent/blob/master/docs/onprem.md). With the next major version of TFS the build agent will support NTLM, which will forego this requirement.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jessehouwing. The link given by you was very informative. It worked for me. "Basic authentication" was disabled in IIS manager. After enabling it, it is working fine now

Comment: Be sure to also secure the server with an ssl Certificate. Or your security credentials will be easily sniffed as they are passed over the line in plain text. .